# Remove hashtag symbol js, by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Tried to search on the forum but could not find anything that would precisely similar to what i need. Im basically trying to remove the `#` symbol from results that im receving, here is the dummy example of the regex.

```js
let postText = 'this is a #test of #hashtags';
var regexp = new RegExp('#([^\\s])', 'g');
postText = postText.replace(regexp, '');

console.log(postText);
```

It gives the following result

```
this is a est of ashtags
```

What do i need to change around so that it removes just the hashtags without cutting the first letter of each word

Comment: Remember when "the hashtag symbol" was just called "hash"? Pepperidge farm remembers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a backreference `$1` as the replacement:

```js
let postText = 'this is a #test of #hashtags';
var regexp = /#(\S)/g;
postText = postText.replace(regexp, '$1');
console.log(postText);
// Alternative with a lookahead:
console.log('this is a #test of #hashtags'.replace(/#(?=\S)/g, ''));
```

Note I suggest replacing the constructor notation with a regex literal notation to make the regex a bit more readable, and changing `[^\s]` with a shorter `\S` (any non-whitespace char).

Here, `/#(\S)/g` matches multiple occurrences (due to `g` modifier) of `#` and any non-whitespace char right after it (while capturing it into Group 1) and `String#replace` will replace the found match with that latter char.

Alternatively, to avoid using backreferences (also called placeholders) you may use a lookahead, as in `.replace(/#(?=\S)/g, '')`, where `(?=\S)` requires a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location. If you need to remove `#` at the end of the string, too, replace `(?=\S)` with `(?!\s)` that will fail the match if the next char is a whitespace.

Comment: Thank you very much, u saved my life :) i hope this thread will help people with the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the following :

```
let postText = 'this is a #test of #hashtags';
postText = postText.replace(/#\b/g, '');
```

It relies on the fact that a `#hashtag` contains a word-boundary between the `#` and the word that follows it. By matching that word-boundary with `\b`, we make sure not to match single `#`.

However, it might match a bit more than you would expect, because the definition of 'word character' in regex isn't obvious : it includes numbers (so `#123` would be matched) and more confusingly, the `_` character (so `#___` would be matched).

I don't know if there's an authoritative source defining whether those are acceptable hashtags or not, so I'll let you judge whether this suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier will be to write your own function which probably will look like this: (covers the usecase when symbol may be repeated)

```
  function replaceSymbol(symbol, string) {
    if (string.indexOf(symbol) < 0) {
      return string;
    }

    while(string.indexOf(symbol) > -1) {
      string = string.replace(symbol, '');
    }

    return string;
  }



var a = replaceSymbol('#', '##s##u#c###c#e###ss is he#re'); // 'success is here'
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the #, the stuff in parens match anything else after said #

```
postText = postText.replace('#', '');
```

This will replace all #

Comment: this will replace only first met #, look at solution above.